# Case statement to replace ifelse in dealing with vectors

Tags: r, if-statement, switch-statement

In using the QCA package, we usually employ `ifelse` to replace dataset columns with dichotomized values.  But I find it ugly to have to use nested `ifelse`s when dealing with fuzzy sets.

Is there a way to use a case statement instead?  `switch` is only for control flow, and does not deal with vectors.

For example:

```
DDDfz $VIES <- ifelse (DDD $vies == "p", 1, 0)
```

is OK, but

```
DDDfz $TIPO <- switch (DDD $tipo, "PD", 0, "PL", 0.5, "MP", 1)
    Error in switch(DDD$tipo, "PD", 0, "PL", 0.5, "MP", 1) : 
    EXPR deve ser um vetor de comprimento 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`switch` is not vectorized and can't be used here. R offers the `factor` data class for tasks like this.

```
factor(c(0, 0.5, 1), levels = c(0, 0.5, 1), 
                     labels = c("PD", "PL", "MP"))
#[1] PD PL MP
#Levels: PD PL MP
```

You also don't need `ifelse` in your first example. You can simply do `as.integer(DDD$vies == "p")`.

PS: A space in front of `$` is a weird code style.

Answer (score 2):

```
#data example
TIPO = c("PD", "PL",  "MP", "PL",  "MP")

# here we create dictionary 
dict = c("PD" = 0, "PL" = 0.5, "MP" = 1)
# further we match dictionary with original values 
recoded_TIPO = dict[TIPO]

# result
recoded_TIPO
```

Answer (score 1):

The R `switch` function is unfortunately quite limited in its usefulness. [The ‹dplyr› package has a nice pattern matching function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.5.0/topics/case_when) that’s more powerful:

```
result = case_when(
    x == 'PD' ~ 0,
    x == 'PL' ~ 0.5,
    x == 'MP' ~ 1
)
```

In this particular case, the other solutions (using factors or a vector) are more concise and also more efficient. But `case_when` is more powerful in general.